# overlaying text over an image

Tags: html, css

Im just getting in to web dev (mainly an iOS, Java, c# programmer). I have a simple problem bt it is anoying.

```
<div id="banner">
    <img src="Styles/Banner.jpg" alt="banner" />
   <div id="bannerText">
    User ID
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a banner which is a simple image (.jpg) and I want to overlay some text. The problem is positioning the text over the banner. I dont realy want to use apsolute positioning. I would like to have both the image and the text centered. The problem is I ony seem to be able to overlap the text over the image when using apsolute positioning, which will be effected if the window is resised. Whats the best/simplist way to do this.

---

Just Like to thank all of you for being so helpful. GC

Comment: Why don't you want to use `position: absolute` which, coincidentally, would be the best tool for this job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/rrsv4HYv)***

Hey now i think you should want to this

**HTML**

```
<div id="banner">
    <img src="http://rapidgator.net/images/pict-download.jpg" alt="banner" />
   <div id="bannerText">
    User ID
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
#banner{
position:relative;
  background:green;
  padding:10px;
}
img{
vertical-align:top;
}
#bannerText{
position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:10px;
  background:red;
}
```

**[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/rrsv4HYv)**

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the parent element (`#banner`) a `position: relative;` to make the absolute position of its child (`#bannerText`) dependent on the banner position and not on the window border.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use image as background instead of `<img>` tag using css like following example

```
#bannerText
  {
    background: url("Styles/Banner.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    width: 123px;
    height: 123px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

If you don't want to use `Position:` 
if you want to use `<img>` then go with  "feeela's" ans